how to calculate average price of each item in inventory php mysql
I have created a warehouse inventory report page. I'm trying to calculate average price of every item present in our warehouse. The items have different price and quantity every time we purchase. For eg. we purchased 10 bottles of water for $2 each but next time we might purchase 20 bottles for $3 each.



Quantity
Unit Price
Total




10
2
20


20
3
60



The average for the bottles will be 80 bottles / 30 bottles = $2.66
But if we transfer 8 bottles from 20 bottles



Quantity
Unit Price
Total




10
2
20


12
3
36



Now the average for the bottles will be 56 bottles / 22 bottles = $2.54
My query to get this is
SELECT 
`inventory`.`name` AS `item_name`, 
`items`.`brand`,
ROUND (AVG(stockreceive_trans.price), 2) AS price,
`categories`.`name` AS `category_name`,
items.measure_unit,
inventory.barcode,
inv_quantity
FROM `inventory`
JOIN `items` ON inventory.barcode = items.barcode            
JOIN `categories` ON inventory.category_id = categories.id
JOIN `stockreceive_trans` ON items.id = stockreceive_trans.item_id
WHERE inventory.warehouse_id = '$warehouse_id'
GROUP BY items.id

but I cannot figure out how to get this right. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Why are you recalculating the average price when you sell some bottles? Although you have fewer bottles they still cost the same as when they were purchased. The total value of stock held is lower but the cost remains the same.

Yes the cost will remain same but average price will change according to the quantities left because each purchase will cost different. This is what I've tried to show in my both example tables

I suppose I don't see why the average price is useful to know. The cost to the business for the water in your warehouse does not change because you sold some bottles, you still spent $80 to buy 30 bottles. The reason I raise this question is because it seems you're mixing inventory management with accounting and in accounting you want to know exact income and expenditure to calculate profit or loss - average values are not normally needed.

You are right, but this is what they require. I have to do what they ask

"I have to do what they ask" - I understand, I've been in that situation myself. You can tell them about any concerns you have about the design but if they don't want to listen, I guess that's their problem. Good luck.

BTW has Art's answer solved your problem or do you still need help?

No, Art couldn't understand my question. I was just trying to show the multiplication process clearly, these are not my db tables. My db tables are in the query I shared. I have multiple entries of each items and I'm only showing average of each record on a single row. Right now we have around 700 items, I cannot show multiple entries of each item

I only have quantity and unit price column in my db table, I'm calculating total and showing the average price. There is no column for total in the db.

Show the queries used to create the tables, along with sample data for each table. If you want, you can use DBFiddle or similar, so other people can execute queries against the tables without trying to work out the structure of the database :)

Here you are with the 3 main tables I'm trying to deal for this query. inventory table
items table
stockreceive_trans table

From the table definitions you created in DBFiddle I can see there are problems with the design which you really should fix, but we can make your query work.
The current structure is as follows:

I've shown the relationship of items and inventory using the item_id but in your query you are using barcode, either should work but since you have a foreign key we should use it and storing the barcode in both tables means the design is not normalised.
Without using any window functions you can group and calculate the sum/avg of each product using a nested query. I've used the least number of fields from the tables to show it working, you can add any extra columns you need.
I have not joined items to inventory as all the information you need to calculate the avg price is available in the stockreceive_trans table.
select 
    item_name
    ,sum(quantity) total_quantity
    ,sum(total_cost) total_cost
    ,ROUND(sum(total_cost)/sum(quantity),2) avg_price
from (
  select 
      item_name 
      ,stockreceive_trans.price
      ,quantity
      ,round(stockreceive_trans.price*quantity, 2) total_cost
  from 
      items
      join stockreceive_trans on items.id = stockreceive_trans.item_id
) stock
group by item_name;

See the updated DBFiddle for a working query.
The result of this query is:



item_name
total_quantity
total_cost
avg_price




Bottled Water
30.000
80.00
2.67



As you have not described how sales are recorded, changing the quantity inserted into the stockreceive_trans will suffice.
INSERT INTO `stockreceive_trans`(
    `id`, `reference_id`, `item_id`, `item_name`,
    `measure_unit`, `barcode`, `warehouse_id`,
    `category_id`, `sub_category`, `quantity`, `price`)
VALUES (2,1,1,'Bottled Water','bottle','62eba14d9e142',1,1,0,20,3);
--                                                           ^^
--                                        change quantity to 12

Running the query again give the result:



item_name
total_quantity
total_cost
avg_price




Bottled Water
22.000
56.00
2.55



Issues with the database design

The name of the table stockreceive_trans implies it's only for incoming stock, where are you recording sold, or outgoing, stock? If you are using a separate table it would be better to combine them.
The inventory table is not needed if the stock_trans table were to record all incoming and outgoing stock movements. A sum of the quantity column (adding positive and negative movements) would give you the current inventory. Storing a total in another table mean at some point the totals will not match.
The tables are not Normalised



Yes, stockreceive_trans is only for incoming stock, for outgoing stock I'm using a different table. I used a single table for both incoming and outgoing stock, I don't exactly remember but I faced some difficulty so I created different table for both operations. Your query is working, I'm very thankful for your help :)

In you question incomplete, as don't share the other table information.
According to your currect table:



Quantity
Unit Price
Total




10
2
20


20
3
60



inforation solution is:

CREATE TABLE T (quantity int, unit_price int, total int);

INSERT INTO T (quantity , unit_price , total ) VALUES 
    ( 10, 2, 20 ),
    ( 20, 3, 60 );

-- ==============

select 
  round(sum(total)/sum(quantity), 2) as avg_bottles_price,
  round(sum(quantity*unit_price)/sum(quantity), 2) as avg_bottles_price_alternative
from T;

I hope issue will resolve your end.
Thank you !!!
